# Fixing the positions correctly so that 3 of the 4 elements on my page don't move with scroll

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a page that's been mocked up in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tBg7/8/).

The page has a `title bar`, a `sidebar`, a `timeline` and a div called `days`

The **only** one that should scroll is `days`.

I'm having trouble with the correct types of positioning so that the `title bar`, `sidebar`, and `timeline` stay 100% fixed as the user scrolls through `.days`.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, in this case I'm not sure `position:fixed` would actually be the easiest approach to the problem. I think the issue actually lies in the heights of your elements.

The `.container` that wraps all the elements has a height of 300px. However, `.days` has no defined height; so even though you specified `overflow-y:scroll`, it won't really scroll - rather, it will just expand to the height required to display all of the content. This isn't immediately apparent because of the `overflow:hidden` on `.container` though, which causes the additional height of `.days` to be hidden.

Specifying a height on `.days` should give you what you want. But what height, exactly? Well, I'm going to assume that you'll want the bottom of `.days` to be the same as the bottom of `.sidebar`, which has a height of 250px. Since `.timeline` (above `.days`) has a height of 12px, then the height you need is 250px - 12px = 238px.

In your CSS definitions, just add this style:

```
.days {
    height: 238px;
}
```

This should let you scroll the content of `.days`, without shifting the positions of its surrounding elements.

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tBg7/10/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. One correction is that the content is `.days` is coming from the server and will be different on every page. For one page `.days` may be 1000px high, other pages it may be 5000px high

Comment: Hmmm, well, the `238px` just defines how tall the viewing window of `.days` is; if the content of the element is longer, it will just scroll further. Unless you want the viewing window to actually be taller?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a try if it serves your purpose. Somewhere above in your comment you said of not being sure of amount of content you would get from back-end, so this approach should take care of it.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/6tBg7/12/)**

**Code**:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.titlebar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top: 50px;
}

.content-area {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left:150px;
}

.timeline {
    height: 12px;
    width:100%;
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;
}

.days {
    background: orange;
}
```

Specifically, have a look at how `position:fixed` is used along with `top`, `left` and `margin-top` and `margin-left`.

Once I wrote about [CSS positioning](http://web-dev-lover.blogspot.in/2014/01/css-position-property.html), it might help you understand it better.